Using Omit and adding the property back still an error
In my Typescript project, I have many modules and entities. I defined these interfaces, which work fine across all modules:
interface Entity {

    id: string;

}

interface Bookmark extends Entity {

    name: string;
    url: string;
    clicks: number;
    tags: string[]

}

interface Note extends Entity {

    // ...

}

const newBookmark: Omit<Bookmark, 'id'> = {

    name: 'ABCDEF',
    url: 'abcdef.com',
    clicks: 10,
    tags: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]

};

In the following create method, I get the error below:
function create<T extends Entity>(data: Omit<T, 'id'>) : void {

    const newEntity: T = { ...data, id: '1234' }; // <-- compilation error

}


Type Omit<T, "id"> & { id: string; } is not assignable to type T.
Omit<T, "id"> & { id: string; } is assignable to the constraint of type T, but T could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint Entity

Omit<T, 'id'> should tell Typescript that the parameter data can be any object without an 'id' property.
Putting the id back in ({ ...data, id: '1234' }) should, at least logically, be a valid T, but it isn't.
I'm aware that assuring Typescript that the object is of type T works:
const newEntity: T = { ...data, id: '1234' } as T; // <-- no error

But this feels more like a workaround.
I'm wondering why Typescript raises this error during compilation, and if there's a better way of solving this?
Typescript Playground

It shouldn't logically be a T because the id property can be narrower than string, as shown here. TS still can't figure out higher order generic operations like Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>~T, but even if it could, your example wouldn't be valid. Do something like this where your types are T & {id: string} and not Omit<T, "id"> & {id: string}. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or, more likely, find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz Thanks for the quick answer. I understand the first sample you gave, that 4321 is narrower than string and that breaks the contract. Please elaborate the solution you gave further: what do you mean with 'if it turns out that id is not narrower than string', can you give an example of both cases?

That's just the normal case, where id is string and not something narrower.  Your own examples assume that case.
